# Response.Write not working inside server control property?

Tags: .net, asp.net, servercontrols

I am not sure why this is not working.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" runat="server" Text='<%= string.Format("{0} <br /> {1}","Part 1", "Part 2") %>' ></asp:Label>
```

I just want to combine two resource string as text of label?

Comment: Instead of just saying it isn't working, tell us what *is* happening.

Comment: It is just print the server tag. not executing

Comment: Actually we have gridview, and for setting heddertext property we uses <%$ to bind it from resource, now i have special scenerio that need to combine two resource key with line break and i have no idea that how two resource key can be bind with expression that's why i uses <%= have any idea how to accomplish this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use databinding instead, `Text='<%# String.Format(...) %>'` and make sure you call DataBind() somewhere in your code.

Comment: yes, but why <%= is not working, i think it is the shortcut of response.write

Comment: I think it is because server control is initialized before page, therefore Response object is not ready yet. And `<%# ... %>` tag does a 'late-binding'.

Comment: This soultion looks accaptable to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set properties of a server control with the `<%= %>` syntax. Either set the Text property from code behind, or use just that `<%= %>` syntax, without a Label.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a server control, it is better to use code-behind and set your label's text in `Page_Load` event handler:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    lblTitle1.Text = String.Format("{0} <br /> {1}","Part 1", "Part 2");
}
```